# unable to add external plugins in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

am a newbie in `ckeditor`, unable to add an external plugin. Have been trying since 2 3 hours. I followed this link http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Tutorial-create-external-plugin-for-CKEDITOR. Followed the steps correctly, but it didn't help. Please helps guys. Thanks!

Comment: able to use the plugin when put inside the plugins folder in ckeditor.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should follow docs.ckeditor.com in a first place, read following article:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro

and you will know how to create your own plugins :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Provide url/path to ckeditor assets */
var ckeditor_assets = 'https://github.com/mtvbrianking/CKEditorTutorial/demo1/assets/ckeditor/';

CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('pbckcode', ckeditor_assets + 'plugins/pbckcode/', 'plugin.js');

CKEDITOR.replace('textArea_name', {
  skin: 'moonocolor,' + ckeditor_assets + 'skins/moonocolor/',
  extraPlugins: 'pbckcode',
  toolbar: [
    ['clipboard', 'undo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
    ['TextColor', 'Bold', 'Italic'],
    ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'],
    ['pbckcode']
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  
<textarea id="textArea_id" name="textArea_name"></textarea>
```

Source: http://brianmatovu.com/ckeditor-setup-configuration/

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why should OP use your code?

Comment: Sorry am quite new to using the forum myself, but the common reason why using external plugins will fail with CKEditor is simply because the editor can't locate the plugin.By specifying where the plugin is located and adding it as an external plugin, you would have avoided that mishap